# Mapping A => Option[B] functions to immutable collections of As

Tags: scala

Is there any equivalent of the following function in Scala's standard library?

```
def traverse[A, B](collection: List[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[List[B]]
```

`traverse` applies a function that can fail to an immutable list. It returns `None` at the first failure. It returns `Some(list)` if everything went fine.

Here I'm using lists, but it could be immutable hash maps for example.

Comment: Probably not, this seems very specific. It's not really clear what this is supposed to do, either. What determines if `Option[List[B]` is `Some` or `None`?

Comment: Looks like `traverseU` from `scalaz`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I added the behaviour of `traverse` to my question.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23914713? That person seems to have been trying to implement something similar. No one found a simple standard library function to answer that question, though.

Comment: @senia Thanks it seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll try it ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments scalaz traverseU is exactly what you want

```
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

  println(list.traverseU(i => Option(i+1)))
  println(list.traverseU(i => if (i>2) Option(i+1) else None))
```

Output:

```
Some(List(2, 3, 4, 5))
None
```

**Update**

With Map it's a little more complicated

```
  val map = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)

 map.toList.traverseU { case (k, v) => Option((k, v+1)) } map (_.toMap)
 map.toList.traverseU { case (k, v) => if (v > 2) Option((k, v)) else None } map (_.toMap)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't figure how to make it work with HashMaps. How would you do?

Comment: @Antoine it works exactly the same with `HashMap`s. What's your specific problem?

Comment: Ok I forgot to call `toList`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `traverseU` from `scalaz` for both `List`s and `Map`s:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

(1 to 3).toList.traverseU{ x => (x > 0) option x }
// Some(List(1, 2, 3))

(1 to 3).toList.traverseU{ x => (x > 1) option x }
// None

import scalaz.std.map._

val m = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3)

m.traverseU{ x => (x > 1) option x }
// None

m.traverseU{ x => (x > 0) option x }
// Some(Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3))
```

You could also use it with `indexedSeq`, `set` and `vector` with additional import from `scalaz.std.<instancesObject>._`.

```
import scalaz.std.indexedSeq._

(1 to 3).traverseU{ _.some }
// Option[IndexedSeq[Int]] = Some(Vector(1, 2, 3))
```

You could also implement [`Traverse`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/#scalaz.Traverse) to use it with other collections.