# Function to determine membership in a list

Tags: list, scala, element

I need to write a program which contains the function
`doesExist: [A](p:A => Boolean) (xs: List[A]) Boolean`.

e.g. `doesExist ((x:Int) => x==2) (List(5,1,2,3)) => true`

It should just return true or false depending on whether the element is found in the list.

Comment: You mean you need to implement the function?

Comment: Please add information on what you've tried so far, what problems you encountered. [ask].

Comment: def doesExist[A](p: A => Boolean)(xs: List[A]): Boolean = {
    xs.foldLeft(false)((acc, elem) => acc || p(elem))
}

Got this compiled, now I try to test on some data, trying that form:
doesExist(2)(List(1,2,3))

No proper reply.

Comment: Solved it, form like that:
doesExist((x:Int) => x==2)(List(1,2,3))

Returns that:
doesExist((x:Int) => x==0)(List(1,2,3))

 res11: Boolean = false

So I think it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the gist of it is to not use the built in function of lists... So here's an alternative using `foldLeft`:

```
def doesExist[A](p: A => Boolean)(xs: List[A]): Boolean = {
    xs.foldLeft(false)((acc, elem) => acc || p(elem))
}
```

Comment: This goes through the whole list even after it's found a true element.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a good exercise to practice pattern-matching:

```
def doesExist[A](p:A => Boolean)(xs: List[A]): Boolean = xs match {
    case Nil => false
    case head :: tail => p(head) || doesExist(p)(tail)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
def doesExist[A](p:A => Boolean)(xs: List[A]) = xs.exists(p)
```

If you cannot use `exists`:

```
def doesExist[A](p:A => Boolean)(xs: List[A]) =
  xs.fold(false)((alreadyFound, a) => alreadyFound || p(a))
```

Comment: The second version searches the whole list even after finding a true element. The first version does not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the Scala 2.11.8 standard library does it.

From [LinearSeqOptimized.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala):

```
  override /*IterableLike*/
  def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var these = this                      // <--- Look, a var!
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      if (p(these.head)) return true      // <--- Look, a return!
      these = these.tail
    }
    false
  }
```

In other words, Scala uses a `while` loop, which mutates a var that points to the next object, and breaks out of the loop when it reaches the desired object.

I found out, when [comparing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914713/how-do-you-stop-building-an-optioncollection-upon-reaching-the-first-none#comment36915774_23916114) to a similar question, that `while` with some sort of mutating iteration variable is the most efficient way to write this in Scala. Pure-functional approaches like recursion, Streams, etc. are slower—as much as 8 times slower (and still without scanning beyond the first 'true' element). I gather that the best approach is to use some kind of mutable iterator when you need to do a linear search and hide it inside a function that presents a pure-functional interface to the rest of the program. The Scala standard library does that in many places for you, so you get the best possible performance with a pure-functional interface.